# VB.NET Process Redirect Output Not Working

Tags: vb.net, shell, command-line

I'm trying to redirect the output from a command-line application in VB.NET, and for some reason it fails to redirect the output. Here's my code:

```
    Dim myProcess As Process = New Process
    myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "g++"
    myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = CMDLineCommand
    myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
    myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    myProcess.Start()
    Dim output As String = myProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd
    myProcess.WaitForExit()
    CMDLineOutputTextBox.Text = output
```

Does anybody know why it's not being redirected? Thanks in advance!

-Neil

EDIT: Here's my full code, in case there's anything weird with my syntax:

```
        Dim myProcess As Process = New Process
        myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "g++"
        myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = CMDLineCommand
        myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
        myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
        myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
        myProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = True
        AddHandler myProcess.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf GotData
        myProcess.Start()
        CMDLineOutputTextBox.Text = ""
        myProcess.BeginOutputReadLine()
```

Later on...

```
Private Sub GotData(sendingProcess As Object, outLine As DataReceivedEventArgs)
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(outLine.Data) Then
            SetText(outLine.Data)
        End If
End Sub

Delegate Sub SetTextCallback(value As String)
Private Sub SetText(ByVal value As String)
    If Me.CMDLineOutputTextBox.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim d As New SetTextCallback(AddressOf SetText)
        Me.Invoke(d, New Object() {value})
    Else
        Me.CMDLineOutputTextBox.Text += value + Environment.NewLine
    End If
End Sub
```

Anything weird?

Answer (score 0):

Your method will work, provided by the time you hit the line where you read the output to the end, all of the output is there.  Since you are using g++, I assume that may not always be the case.  You will probably be better off using the OutputDataReceived Event and capturing the data from that.

```
Dim myProcess As Process = New Process
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "ping"
myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "www.google.com"
myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
myProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = True 
AddHandler myProcess.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf GotData
myProcess.Start()
myProcess.BeginOutputReadLine()
```

Then you handle the event like this:

```
Private Sub GotData(sendingProcess As Object, outLine As DataReceivedEventArgs)
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(outLine.Data) Then
        SetText(outLine.Data)
    End If
End Sub 

Delegate Sub SetTextCallback(value As String)
Private Sub SetText(ByVal value As String)
    If Me.TextBox3.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim d As New SetTextCallback(AddressOf SetText)
        Me.Invoke(d, New Object() {value})
    Else
        Me.TextBox3.Text += value + Environment.NewLine
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I added my full code above... For some reason, it's still not displaying the command-line output in the CMDLineOutputTextBox text box :P

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the SetText method and make sure it is getting there.  Is your textbox set to multiline?

Comment: Yes, the textbox is multiline.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed the waitforExit seems to make the code lock during the invoke.required check. When I take out the waitforexit it works.

Comment: You mean the waitForExit actually waits? :)